# what is the best document indexer with a good api out there?

Tags: .net, open-source, search-engine, document

I'm looking for a open source/paid document indexing software which will allow me search through the various documents(doc,docx,pdf,rtf...) with a .net API.

does any one using this kind of thing?

Answer (score 1):

Searching and indexing are two different things, however generally related. For a decent search engine my favourite is [Lucene](http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/) however [RavenDB](http://ravendb.net/) may be preferable.

Hopefully someone can suggest a good indexer.

For a complete solution you might want to look ay implementing the enterprise search engine in SharePoint.

Another alternative is to purchase a Google local search server.

Answer (score 0):

You can go for [Apache Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) : It includes **powerful text search** , **dynamic clustering** , **geospatial search** and many more.

Answer (score 0):

Also this
http://www.dtsearch.com/PLF_engine_2.html

Some documentation:http://support.dtsearch.com/webhelp/dtSearchNetApi2/frames.html?frmname=topic&frmfile=dtSearch__Engine.html